# touchesbegan touches only registers one touch even with two fingers

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i touch down at same time with two fingers.  i get [touches count]=>1 and [[event allTouches] count] =>2

Shouldn't i get 2 for both of them?

Also, when i first place 1 finger down then another on the same cell.  The second finger event doesn't cause touchesBegan to drigger?  Shouldn't it call touchesBegan twice?

i have a table cell where i set:

```
multipleTouchEnabled = YES;
```

here is my touches began:

```
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    NSLog(@"began touch count %d", [touches count]);
    NSLog(@"all touches %d", [[event allTouches] count]);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be something going on with the touches when using a `UITableViewCell`. My guess is that is has to do with the built in handling of detecting swipes and touches for the cell as well as being able to handle the scrolling of the `UITableView` itself. As a workaround you can add you own view to the cell's `contentView` to be able to detect the touches. Something along the lines of:

```
MyCustomView *customView = [[MyCustomView alloc] initWithFrame:...];
customView.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;
[cell.contentView addSubview:customView];
[customView release];
```

where you are creating the cell, probably in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`